# "Node transform 'set' requires one operand!" when trying to use tablegen

Tags: llvm

I was trying to get the C65 LLVM-Backend (https://github.com/Peppar/llvm-C65) to work with LLVM 8.0.1 (the original version if made for LLVM 3).
After a few fixes, everything compiled properly, but there are a few error generated by TableGen.

The error messages are all like this:

```
add_frag(dst, src1, src2):  (set node:{}:$dst, (add:{} node:{}:$src1, node:{}:$src2))
Included from F:/Projects/llvm-65816/lib/Target/C65/C65.td:59:
F:/Projects/llvm-65816/lib/Target/C65\C65InstrInfo.td:1353:1: error: In add_frag: Node transform 'set' requires one operand! (got 2)
def add_frag : PatFrag<(ops node:$dst, node:$src1, node:$src2),
^
```

This is the line causing it (At https://github.com/Peppar/llvm-C65/blob/master/C65InstrInfo.td#L1353):

```
def add_frag : PatFrag<(ops node:$dst, node:$src1, node:$src2),
                       (set node:$dst, (add node:$src1, node:$src2))>;
```

The TableGen Language is not that well documented as the LLVM IR is, so I am struggling to find out what the problem is, but I think it is caused by the type.

I have following questions:

1. How to fix it?
2. What does `node` mean and why is this a problem in this case (if it is)?

Comment: Maybe you have to replace `node` with `dag`?

Comment: Replacing node with dag doesn't work.

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Comment: @S.S.Anne Yes and no. I fixed it back then, but I think I just rewrote the expressions with `node` to match modern LLVM. Unfortunately, I can't find the code :/